# How can I include the end date in np.busday_count?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

By default, the function excludes the last date while calculating business days. Adding 1 is not a good idea. If the last day is a Sunday and adding 1 will give incorrect business days. Is there a parameter that handles this or a way to get business days with the last date included?

Comment: if the upper limit is excluded, why should adding one day be "not a good idea"?

Comment: @FObersteiner - Consider the start day is Monday and the end day is Friday, adding 1 makes business days 5, which is correct. If the end date is Saturday or Sunday, then adding 1 will make business days 6.

Comment: Did you test that, can you add an example to the question?

Comment: @FObersteiner - np.busday_count('2022-11-28', '2022-12-02') and np.busday_count('2022-11-28', '2022-12-05')